# Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed despite qualifying ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running into an issue and I can't figure it out. Questions with the same error seem to have a different issue.

I have the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Bank_match()
    Dim x As Range, y As Range
    Dim FirstSheet As Worksheet, SecondSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Txn_count_1 As Integer, Txn_count_2 As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Set FirstSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set SecondSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With FirstSheet
        Set x = Cells.Find(What:="Description", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues _
            , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            Txn_count_1 = Range(x.offset(1, 0), x.offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)).Count
    End With

    With SecondSheet
        Set y = Cells.Find(What:="Description", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues _
            , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            Txn_count_2 = Range(y.offset(1, 0), y.offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)).Count
    End With

    For i = 1 To Txn_count_1
            If FirstSheet.Range(x).offset(i, 1).Value = SecondSheet.Range(y).offset(i, 2).Value Or _
            FirstSheet.Range(x).offset(i, 2).Value = SecondSheet.Range(y).offset(i, 1).Value Then
                FirstSheet.Range(x.offset(i, 1)).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                SecondSheet.Range(y.offset(i, 1)).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Effectively, I'm trying to iterate through bank statements and highlight the rows of transactions that appear on both sheets. My problem is that I get the error on the 'If statement' line.

At first I thought it might be my sheet references, but if I replace 'FirstSheet' and 'SecondSheet' with Worksheets("Sheet1") and Worksheets("Sheet2") respectively, I then get "Application-defined or object-defined error" on the same line. I get the same error if I also qualify the range with 'ThisWorkbook'.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the `FirstSheet.Range` and `SecondSheet.Range`... `x` and `y` are already range objects:

```
If x.Offset(i, 1).Value = y.offset(i, 2).Value...
```

Though you need to check if the `Find` was successful... otherwise `x` or `y` might be `Nothing`... using the following:

```
If Not x Is Nothing Then ' and similarly for y
```

And you are missing a period `.` before `Cells` and `Range`

```
Set x = .Cells
Set y = .Cells
Txn_count_1 = .Range(...
Txn_count_2 = .Range(...
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and clear advice. No run-time errors now, but now I'm having issues with my offsetting. I'll see if I can figure that one out :)